# Title editing with System.Drawing.Image not working for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, metadata, jpeg, exif

I have created a few functions to edit the Exif metadata the Jpeg image, right now I am able to edit the comment but it doesn't work when I tried to edit my title, there were no errors displayed, and I want to save it by replacing the original files, this is the code I have created so far:

```
System.Drawing.Image image = null;
    protected void EditCommentBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath);
        PropertyItem propItem = image.PropertyItems[0];
        using (var file = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath))
        {

            propItem.Id = 0x9286; //Usercomment
            propItem.Type = 2;
            propItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("HelloWorld\0");
            propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length;
            file.SetPropertyItem(propItem);

            PropertyItem propItem1 = file.PropertyItems[file.PropertyItems.Count() - 1];
            string newFilename = "newfilename.jpg";
            file.Save(newFilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }

    }
    protected void EditTitleBtn_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath);
        PropertyItem propItem = image.PropertyItems[0];
        using (var file = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filepath))
        {
            propItem.Id = 0x0320; //Title
            propItem.Type = 2;
            propItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("testtitle\0");
            propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length;
            file.SetPropertyItem(propItem);

            PropertyItem propitem1 = file.PropertyItems[file.PropertyItems.Count() - 1];
            string newFilename = "newfilename.jpg";
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                image.Dispose();
                File.Delete(filepath);
            }
            file.Save(newFilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
```

and there was an error display while saving the file, since I want to replace the jpeg that I have edited, I tried to use the File.Exits and File.Delete but it didnt work for me, this is the error it display

> The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being
>   used by another process

eventhough I disposed the image beforehand, but I can delete other files, just not the one I used to check the condition for in the `if` block.

---

So right now the problems I have right now is 
**1.Cant change the Exif metadata of the title of the Jpeg image(RESOLVED)**
**2.Cant replace the originals jpeg file with the edited jpeg file**

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently I found the reason why it didn't work for me, its because I have used the wrong ID for the title, so that why I couldn't change the Title no matter how many times I tried.

The correct ID for the title would be `propItem.Id = 0x010E;` and the rest of the codes is pretty much the same as the EditComment Event, as they used the same data type.